Which film or show is this picture of Ben Turpin taken from?

I originally found this picture from a postcard which have signature of Ben Turpin
http://www.trishautographs.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Store_Code=THA&Product_Code=0521&Category_Code=VH
I want to know which film or show did this picture taken from, since I have never seen this look of Ben Turpin from all his works.

This is not from any particular Ben Turpin film, simply a posed photo for his fans, circa 1918. If you want to know more about Turpin, look for a great book called FOR ART'S SAKE – The Biography & Filmography of Ben Turpin.
